# Webpack sass loading Error with style.scss in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass, platform-server

I'm trying to do add postcss-loader to Angular 4 with platform-server rendering, I keep getting the error as below, basically what I'm trying to do is adding style.scss as global scss to my webpack process, similar the way it's working in cli...

```
 ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader/lib?{}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles.scss
        Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: /Users/alireza.dezfoolian/Desktop/Angular 4/web-app/src
            at /Users/alireza.dezfoolian/Desktop/Angular 4/web-app/node_modules/postcss-load-config/index.js:51:26
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the sass-loader.

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

Comment: I did this, but still getting this Error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add node-sass to your project. To install node-sass you need node-gyp globally installed. [Check this installation part for node-gyp.](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and is because of the node-sass package. So, it is necessary to rebuild your node-sass package.

Run the cmd: `npm rebuild node-sass` to make sure it is ready.

*See the below snippet of my ubuntu terminal:*

```
asus@asus:~/Documents/demo$ npm rebuild node-sass                            

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /home/asus/Documents/demo/node_modules/node-sass   
> node scripts/install.js                                                    

Cached binary found at /home/asus/.npm/node-sass/4.5.3/linux-x64-48_binding.n
ode                                                                          

> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall /home/asus/Documents/demo/node_modules/node-sas
s                                                                            
> node scripts/build.js                                                      

Binary found at /home/asus/Documents/demo/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux
-x64-48/binding.node                                                         
Testing binary                                                               
Binary is fine                                                               
node-sass@4.5.3 /home/asus/Documents/demo/node_modules/node-sass
```

**And my issue get resolved out!!!**